# Python Mysqldb cursor has no attribute 'fetchAll'

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'fetchAll'".  My `rowCount` is 451 and all queries are working.

I've looked into this problem and most mistakes involve calling `fetchAll()` on the return value of `cursor.execute()`, but this is not what I'm doing here.

```
#initialize cursors
presswiseCursor = presswiseConnection.cursor()
localCursor = localConnection.cursor()

#products
#initialize table
localCursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;")
localCursor.execute("CREATE TABLE products (id INT NOT NULL, description VARCHAR(255));")
#get data from presswise
rowCount = presswiseCursor.execute("SELECT DISTINCT id, description FROM list_product;")
print(rowCount)
rows = presswiseCursor.fetchAll()
#add data to local
for row in rows:
    localCursor.execute(f'INSERT INTO products (id, description) VALUES({row[0]}{row[1]})')
```

I would like to iterate over the results of the query and have used this exact technique before.  What's wrong with my code?

Comment: I resolved this issue by iterating over the cursor variable i.e. `for row in presswiseCursor`.

Answer (score 3):

use fetchall() instead of fetchAll() in python3.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried not attributing the `cursor.execute()` to a variable and then calling the `cursor.fetchAll()` ?

Then to get the number of rows just do `len(rows)` after `fetchAll()`

Side note, but why are you using triple quotes on the sql statement?

Comment: Sorry, edited the code.  Triple quotes were left over from a longer query!  Yes, I tried without assigning the cursor to rowCount, but even my current code should work... [reference](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/db-sig/2002-November/002906.html)

Comment: `rowCount` isn't necessary, I just included it to show that I was actually getting data from the cursor.